# Even if the interview went terribly yesterday, Cheryl got the job

Tags: word-choice, conditional-constructions, modality

> > Even if the interview went terribly yesterday, Cheryl got the job.
>
> You have not talked to Cheryl since her interview. You imagine that
>   the interview went terribly, but you think she probably got the job
>   anyway.([original explanation](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/even.html))

I was studying "even if", I came across this sentence.Even though I am able to understand what "even if" implies and connotes, I still have a problem with its usage that for me the sentence should have written

> Even if the interview went terribly yesterday, Cheryl would get the
>   job. ( my sentence)

Because if we use "got", it reduces the meaning of imaginary which the sentence have to have.

Comment: I think you are right. Using **would get** instead of **got** changes the meaning of the sentence. While using **got** means that **he landed into the job**, using **would get** indicates that **he has not yet got the job, but the possibility is that he might get**.

Answer (score 1):

"got" in this case is used as a sort of retrospective statement of certainty. It means "must [surely] have gotten". In that sense, it's basically the other side of "would get": one is phrased from a pre-interview perspective*, and the other from a post-interview perspective.

However the sentence is phrased, though, it is an assurance that Cheryl's success in getting the job was essentially guaranteed even in the worst case imaginable; "got" vs "would get" vs "must have gotten" is mostly just a matter of how clear you want to be at the expense of being brief.

<sub>*But note that the rest of the sentence is, in any case, in the past tense. This leads to a clash between implied tenses that is a little jarring.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the conditional structure correctly, technically. But is there really a condition for a certain event? There is the word *if* in this sentence that is confusing me and it makes you use conditionals. Just like we learned in school :D

But when I think more about it, this is actually the opposite of a real condition since it doesn't matter what happens. Even if [whatever] she got the job. So maybe there are some phrases containing "if" without calling for a conditional?

("Because if we use "got", it **will**(?) reduce<strike>*s*</strike> the meaning of imaginary which the sentence have to have.")